# Moment Estimator in Multivariate Hypergeometric Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, hypergeometric-function

We suppose that a population contains $K$ different types of object, with R.V $X_1$, $X_2$, ... , $X_K$, being the number of each type, and we have $\sum_{k = 1}^{K}X_{k} = N$. Then, a simple random sample of size $n$ is taken and the number of each type, $Y_1$, $Y_2$, ... , $Y_K$ is obtained so that $\sum_{k = 1}^{K}Y_{k} = n$. I noticed that this can be modeled by a multivariate hypergeometric distribution:
$$
P(Y_1, Y_2, ... ,Y_K|x_1, x_2, ... , x_K) = \frac{\prod_{k = 1}^{K} {x_k \choose y_k}}{{N \choose n}},
$$
with mean and variances
$$
E(Y_k|x_k) = n\frac{x_k}{N} \quad \text{and} \quad Var(Y_k|x_k) = n\frac{x_k}{N}(1-\frac{x_k}{N})\frac{N-n}{N-1}.
$$
**Assuming that the numbers of $X_1, X_2, ... , X_K$ are unknown but the $N$ is known. I am wondering how can I obtain the method of moments estimator for $X_k$ and the variance of this estimator along with an estimator of this variance?**

Comment: Are $X_i$ and $x_i$ the same thing?  And are the $y_i$ observations of the $Y_i$?  And you know $N$ and the $y_i$?

Comment: The natural estimator of $x_k$ is $\frac{N}{n}Y_k$ as you simply scale up the observations to fit the total population.  Is that the method of moments estimator?  If so, its variance given $x_k$ is $\left(\frac Nn\right)^2 \mathrm{Var}(Y_k \mid x_k)  = \frac1n  x_k(N-{x_k})\frac{N-n}{N-1}$.  You would need to use the method of moments  again for an estimator of that.

Comment: Hi @Henry, $X_i = x_i$ and $Y_i = y_i$. Yes, we know the $N$ and the $y_i$. I am wondering what is the variance of the unconditional $X_i$?